# BIOS and Grub not accessible on boot Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, grub2, kubuntu, bios

## Issue

When booting, I cannot access the BIOS or Grub menus. Despite this, the computer boots normally, without issue. I am not dual booting. This computer only runs Kubuntu 22.04. When I first set up this computer, both were working fine. I'm not sure exactly when they stopped working, but it appears that it happened for both at the same time, leading me to think it may be related. Though, I'm not confident.

## What I've tried

- Enter BIOS using del/esc/F2 and other keys.
- Hold the power button for 4 seconds when turning on. This has only resulted in the computer shutting down.
- Enter Grub by clicking shift repeatedly during boot.
- Check Grub settings to ensure that `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="menu"`
- Used `update-grub` after any changes to ensure they're applied.
- Tested if it might be a graphical issue by using Grub-Customizer to update the theme. This had no impact.
- Tried contacting MSI about BIOS. They will not help because I'm not running Windows as my OS.

Any help would be appreciated!

## System information:

$ `neofetch`

```
Host: MS-7D25 2.0 
Kernel: 5.15.0-67-generic 
Uptime: 10 mins 
Packages: 3280 (dpkg), 15 (flatpak), 6 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.1.16 
Resolution: 3440x1440 
DE: Plasma 5.24.7 
WM: KWin 
Theme: [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Tela-dark [Plasma], Tela-dark [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: konsole 
CPU: 12th Gen Intel i9-12900K (24) @ 5.100GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 
GPU: Intel AlderLake-S GT1 
Memory: 5642MiB / 64096MiB
```

## BIOS information:

$ `sudo dmidecode -t bios`

```
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.5.0 present.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 26 bytes
BIOS Information
        Vendor: American Megatrends International, LLC.
        Version: A.70
        Release Date: 06/23/2022
        Address: 0xF0000
        Runtime Size: 64 kB
        ROM Size: 32 MB
        Characteristics:
                PCI is supported
                BIOS is upgradeable
                BIOS shadowing is allowed
                Boot from CD is supported
                Selectable boot is supported
                BIOS ROM is socketed
                EDD is supported
                Japanese floppy for NEC 9800 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
                Japanese floppy for Toshiba 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
                5.25"/360 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
                8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
                Serial services are supported (int 14h)
                Printer services are supported (int 17h)
                CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
                USB legacy is supported
                BIOS boot specification is supported
                Targeted content distribution is supported
                UEFI is supported
        BIOS Revision: 5.25

Handle 0x0061, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
BIOS Language Information
        Language Description Format: Abbreviated
        Installable Languages: 1
                enUS
        Currently Installed Language: enUS
```

## GRUB information:

$ `cat /etc/default/grub`

```
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="menu"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="3"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT="$GRUB_TIMEOUT"
# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE="3440x1440"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="false"
GRUB_THEME="/boot/grub/themes/Stylish/theme.txt"

export GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="light-gray/black"
export GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="magenta/black"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
```

## Boot errors

$ `sudo grep error /var/log/dmesg`

```
[    2.500552] kernel: usb 1-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[    2.864551] kernel: usb 1-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[    3.100556] kernel: usb 1-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[    4.348414] kernel: usb 1-7: device not accepting address 8, error -71
[    4.892416] kernel: usb 1-7: device not accepting address 9, error -71
[    7.815714] kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
[    8.263956] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.264270] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-65.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.691540] kernel: EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
```

Comment: Shift key is only for BIOS boot. With UEFI boot you press escape key right after UEFI/BIOS screen & before grub normally appears. If you have fast start up on in UEFI settings you may not have time to press any keys. Then you can try full power down and "cold" boot, not "warm" reboot. Cold boot has UEFI scan system for what hardware you have & gives just enough time to press a key. Warm reboot with fast start on assumes no system changes & immediately boot default.

Comment: Hi @oldfred. Thanks for the response. I don't notice any difference between cold and warm boot. The issue appears during restart and when I shutdown and turn the computer on again.

The note on using ESC instead of Shift proved interesting, though. When I click ESC during boot up, it seems to prevent the system from booting normally. This makes me think that the ESC button did somehow cause it to enter grub but for some reason I can't see it. Notably, I also can't see the UEFI/BIOS screen before grub appears. 

Perhaps errors would be logged somewhere?

Comment: I do not think UEFI or grub have logs. Log starts with the dmesg you posted. With only one install, grub auto boots default unless you do interrupt it. Where to press escape can be tricky. Do you have UEFI Secure Boot on? If so, try with it off.

Comment: I don't remember if Secure Boot is on or off. Would it be possible to change this setting without entering the BIOS?

Comment: Not that I know of. You can check if it is on or not as Boot-Repair reports it. `mokutil --sb-state`

Comment: Hi @oldfred. Sorry for the delayed response. SecureBoot is disabled according to `mokutil --sb-state`. Can the issue you're imaging still occur if SecureBoot is off?

Comment: Can you get to grub menu with escape? I replace quiet,splash with noplymouth. But do not know if your theme could be an issue. I never have used a theme.